# Pandas datetime difference in Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows, datetime, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've a program that divides the datetime in minutes - hours.
It works well in Windows but trying it on server or WSL, it didn't work

```
    filter_by = pd.Timestamp("today").floor("H") - pd.offsets.Minute(
        int(time)
    )
```

Same code running in WSL,
I get

```
2021-11-17T17:45:00.000000000
```

While running in Windows, I get the correct time

```
2021-11-17T23:30:00.000000000
```

I've changed the Ubuntu time settings as well to Asia/Kolkata, Windows is on Asia/Kolkata still it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect different time zone settings on Windows and WSL (not sure if the settings you changed actually have an effect on what Python/pandas uses). Try `pd.Timestamp('today', tz='UTC')` and you should get results that agree.

Comment: Hey @MrFuppes thanks, but even that didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL2 Clock is out of sync with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086856/wsl2-clock-is-out-of-sync-with-windows)

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the solutions i could find,

changing the time offset to python is what worked for me

```
    tz_IN = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
    datetime_IN = datetime.datetime.now(tz_IN) - datetime.timedelta(
        minutes=int(time)
    )
```

Comment: What is variable `time`?

Comment: @MrFuppes that's a number input given by the user
You can try it live here [link](https://Kaviharjani.com) 
The 15-30-45 time bifurcation is time variable

Comment: if this is just an offset, I don't think it is relevant for the question, no? Also, `pd.Timestamp("today").floor("H")` and `datetime.datetime.now(tz_IN)` are different in that the first is floored to the hour while the second is not.

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks for the suggestion i switched to python and worked as I didn't want to spend more time, and if someone is stuck on similar problem could switch if needed a quick solution but still I wonder why was the `pd.Timestamp("today").floor("H")` working in windows OS but not ubuntu, however, +1 for replying :)