# unable to change timezone

Tags: node.js, docker, timezone

I'm trying to change the timezone of my container into "Europe/paris", I saw I had to set TZ environment variable so I did this, but it doesn't change the timezone..

here's my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /pind

WORKDIR /pind


ENV TZ Europe/Paris
RUN apt update && apt install tzdata -y

ENV PRODUCTION="true"

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD npm run start
```

and the output of the command **date** in my container :
[image]

but the real time in Europe/Paris timezone is 16:21

Comment: CEST is the correct time zone, so your setting has worked. If you're running Windows and WSL2, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086856/wsl2-clock-is-out-of-sync-with-windows. I had lots of issues with the clock on my machine when I ran WSL2.

Answer (score 1):

For an alpine based image you have to install the `tzdata` first. (see this issue [here](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136))

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ Europe/Paris
```

Comment: Did you read the question? In the dockerfile source: `ENV TZ Europe/Paris
RUN apt update && apt install tzdata -y` .. and `apt` is the package-manager for Debian and derivatives (as `apk` is for Alpine).